# Write skew in a snapshot isolation level

Tags: concurrency, mvcc, snapshot-isolation, write-skew

Let's consider a scenario of a write skew below.

[image]

In an MVCC protocol for snapshot isolation, let's assume the initial state is this:

| Item | Version | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| on_call | 3 | [Alice, Bob] |

Then transition TA started and given a unique timestamp of 5 and after some time transition TB will start with a timestamp of 7. Both read **on_call** and return the value [Alice, Bob] as version 3 is less than both timestamps 5 and 7.

Representing the above statement in a table:

| TA(5) | TB(7) |
| --- | --- |
| R(on_call) = [Alice, Bob] |  |
|  | R(on_call) = [Alice, Bob] |

After this TA starts a write and the current version(3) is lower than the transaction's timestamp(5), It's able to add it to the DB. making the state as

| Item | Version | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| on_call | 3 | [Alice, Bob] |
| on_call | 5 | [Bob] |

| TA(5) | TB(7) |
| --- | --- |
| R(on_call) = [Alice, Bob] |  |
|  | R(on_call) = [Alice, Bob] |
| W(on_call, Alice, false) |  |

After that TB starts a write call and finds out the current version is 5 and TB's timestamp is 7. And as all transactions running MVCC will record all active transactions in the beginning. It figured that the current on_call version 5 was made by an active transaction and TB will restart with a new timestamp. Which is a valid case here.

I have read that snapshot isolation doesn't support write skew but in the above case, I don't see a problem.

Can someone please tell me if there is an issue with the above use case?
And redirect me to some docs, that can prove write skew happens in a snapshot isolation.